# Fast children zombies in the original Dawn of the dead

Tags: zombie, dawn-of-the-dead-1978

Near the start of Dawn when they stop to refuel the helicopter one of the characters is attacked by two zombified children that appear to be moving much faster than any of the other zombies.

Was this just a production goof due to using child actors, are they not actually moving faster or would there be some in universe reason that children zombies would move faster?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the clip you referenced. at time 3:34

The children seem to be trotting, almost running.  It is never explained in the movie, but my guess is that having a lower center of gravity they have less trouble balancing and can move quicker.

Comment: Ironically this video is dead

Comment: In 28 Days Later, it is a child extra who speaks, saying "I hate you!" or something. Now, if that was improv, the kid is pretty bright even if he does not take direction so well; maybe that is all we is seeing kids who also do not listen or perhaps zombified kids have more mental abilities than adults.

Comment: It's resting @Valorum.